# Let $a$ be even and not a multiple of $10$, then there exists a constant $c$ such that $s(a^k)>c \log k$ for all $k \geq 2$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation

I found this problem:

> Let $a$ be even and not a multiple of $10$, then there exists a constant $c$ such that $$s(a^k)>c \log k$$ for all $k \geq 2$. Here, $s(a)$ is the digit sum of $a$.

with this solution:
[Proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IUa0.jpg)

I get the main idea of the proof but I do not get the end:

> It follows that if $k \geq b_i$ holds, then
> $$
> s(a^k)\geq i-1 \geq \frac{i}{2}.
> $$
> Thus, if $C^i \geq b_i$ for all $i \geq 1$, the statement follows.

My question is: How does it follow? I do not get how the inequality with $\log k$ is proven and I am not even sure if it is a logarithm base $10$. Can someone explain to me how to conclude the statement? Why do we say $i-1 \geq \frac{i}{2}$ and why do we have to recall $C^i \geq b_i$?

For me this just proves that it grows to infinity.

Comment: Almost the same question was posted recently. For the sake of future readers so that they can have access to all of the answers, I put the link of the other post here. In this way, the two posts will be linked together.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4865447/there-exists-a-constant-c-if-a-positive-integer-a-is-even-and-not-a-multiple/4865630#4865630

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea (which needs a little bit of fixing up) is as follows:

1. Let $i=\log_C k=(\log k)/(\log C)$.
2. Then by the definition of logarithms to the base $C$, $k=C^i$.
3. Since $C^i\ge b_i$, $k\ge b_i$.
4. Then by the earlier part of the proof, $s(a^k)\ge i-1$.
5. If $i\ge 2$, $i-1\ge i/2$.
6. From 1, 4 and 5, $s(a^k)\ge (1/(2\log C)) \log k$.
7. So the claim is true for any constant $c$ between 0 and $1/(2\log C)$.

Changing the base of a logarithm rescales it by a constant factor.  So, in a quotient of logarithms, you don't need to worry about the base of the logarithms, since it will cancel.  For the same reason, you don't need to worry about the base of the logarithm when you read "there exists a constant $c$ such that, ..., $c \log k$, ...", since changing the base of the logarithm has the same effect as rescaling $c$.

This argument needs to be patched up slightly because it assumes that $i$ is an integer and at least 2, but this will not necessarily be true for $i=\log_C k$.  However, you can use a slightly more complicated argument.

1. Since $s(a^k)$ is always nonzero, it's at least 1.  So, by making $c$ small enough, you can make the statement $s(a^k)>c\log k$ true whenever $\log_C k<2$.  Assume then that $\log_C k\ge 2$.
2. Now let $i$ be the greatest integer no more than $\log_C k$.  Since $\log_C k\ge 2$, $i$ will be at least 2.
3. Since $i\le \log_C k$, $C^i\le k$.
4. Since $C^i\ge b_i$, from 3, $k\ge b_i$.
5. Then by the earlier part of the proof, $s(a^k)\ge i-1$.
6. Since $i\ge 2$, $i-1\ge i/2$.
7. Since $i$ is the greatest integer no more than $\log_C k$ and $\log_C k\ge 2$, $i\ge (\log_C k)-1\ge (\log_C k)/2$.
8. From 5, 6 and 7, $s(a^k)\ge (\log_C k)/4 =(1/(4 \log C)) \log k.$
9. So the claim is true if, as well as taking $c$ small enough to satisfy step 1, we take $c$ to be between 0 and $1/(4 \log C)$.