# There exists a constant $c$ if a positive integer $a$ is even and not a multiple of $10$, the sum of the digits of $a^k\ge c\log k$ for all $k\ge 2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

I'm going through *Number Theory:Concepts And Problems* by Titu Andreescu, and I'm stuck on exercise 2.43.

The question says:

> Prove that there exists a constant $c > 0$ with the following property:
> if a positive integer $a$ is even and not a multiple of $10$,then the sum of the digits of $a^k$ is greater than $c \log k$ for all $k\ge 2$

But I don't see how the author arrives at the answer.Especially I do not know what the motivation is for defining a sequence $ \left(b_{n}\right)_{n \geq 0}$  by  $b_{0} = 0 $ and  $b_{n+1} = 1+\left[b_{n} \log_{2}(10)\right]$ .

> Proof. Define a sequence $ \left(b_{n}\right)_{n \geq 0}$  by  $b_{0} = 0 $ and  $b_{n+1} = 1+\left[b_{n} \log _{2}(10)\right]$ . This sequence is increasing and $ b_{n+1} \leq\left(1+\log _{2}(10)\right) b_{n} $ for $ n \geq 1$ , thus  $b_{n} \leq c^{n}$  for all $ n \geq 1 $, where  $c = 1+\log _{2}(10)$ .
>
> Suppose now that $ k \geq b_{n}$  and write  $a^{k} = c_{0}+10 c_{1}+\ldots$  in base $10 $. For each  $2 \leq j \leq n$  we have that  $2^{b_{j}} $ divides  $a^{k}$  and since $ 2^{b_{j}}$  also divides $ c_{b_{j}} 10^{b_{j}}+c_{b_{j}+1} 10^{b_{j}+1}+\ldots$ , it follows that  $2^{b_{j}} $ divides $ c_{0}+10 c_{1}+\ldots+c_{b_{j}-1} 10^{b_{j}-1}$ . Note that this last number is nonzero since  $c_{0} \neq 0 $ by assumption. We deduce that $ 2^{b_{j}} \leq c_{0}+10 c_{1}+\ldots+c_{b_{j}-1} 10^{b_{j}-1}$ . Assuming that  $c_{b_{j-1}}, \ldots, c_{b_{j}-1}$  are all zero we deduce that  $2^{b_{j}}<10^{b_{j-1}}$ , contradicting the definition of the sequence  $\left(b_{n}\right)_{n \geq 0}$ . Thus for each $ 2 \leq j \leq n $ there is at least one nonzero digit between  $c_{b_{j-1}}$, $\ldots$, $c_{b_{j}-1}$ . It follows that if  $k \geq b_{n}$ , then the sum of digits of  $a^{k}$  is at least $ n-1 \geq n / 2$ . Taking into account that $ b_{n} \leq c^{n}$  for all  $n \geq 1 $, the result follows.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out the edits I made to your $\rm\LaTeX$. You can call $\log$ with `\log`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at the problem from another angle. Assume $b_1, b_2, b_3, ...$ is an increasing sequence such that $b_1=1$ and for every $i \in \mathbb N,$ $2^{b_{i+1}}$ has $b_i+1$ digits. **At first glance, this definition may seem strange, but what does that mean? In fact, what it means is the reasoning behind its definition!** This definition simply implies that:

$$2^{b_{i+1}}>c_0+c_1 {10}^1+c_2 {10}^2+ ... +c_{b_{i-1}}{10}^{b_{i-1}}+...+c_{b_{i}-1}{10}^{b_i-1}, \ \ (*)$$

where the coefficients belong to $\{0,1, ..,9\}.$

Now, let's assume $k \geq b_{n+1}$. Considering $a^k=c_0+c_1 {10}^1+c_2 {10}^2+ ... $ (in base $10$ and $c_0 \neq 0$), we have:

$$a^k \geq 2^{b_{n+1}} >c_0+c_1 {10}^1+c_2 {10}^2+ ... +c_{b_{n-1}}{10}^{b_{n-1}}+...+c_{b_{n}-1}{10}^{b_n-1} \neq 0. $$

Now, note that $2^{b_{n}}|a^k.$ So,

$$2^{b_{n}} | c_0+c_1 {10}^1+c_2 {10}^2+ ... +c_{b_{n-1}}{10}^{b_{n-1}}+...+c_{b_{n}-1}{10}^{b_n-1}.$$

Since $2^{b_{n}} >c_0+c_1 {10}^1+c_2 {10}^2+ ... +c_{b_{n-2}}{10}^{b_{n-2}}+...+c_{b_{n-1}-1}{10}^{b_{n-1}-1}$, at least one of the elements of the set
$$\{c_{b_{n-1}} , ...,  c_{b_{n}-1}\}$$

must be non zero. Doing the same process with $2^{b_{n-1}}|a^k$, we obtain that at least one of the elements of the set
$$\{c_{b_{n-2}} , ...,  c_{b_{n-1}-1}\}$$

must be non zero. Doing the same process inductively backwards, we obtain that $n-1$ coefficients of $a^k=c_0+c_1 {10}^1+c_2 {10}^2+ ... $ (in base $10$)  are non zero. Therefore, for $k \geq b_{n+1}$, the sum of the digits of $a^k$ is at least $n-1.$ **Now, it should make sense why we wanted the inequality $(*)$ to hold.**

At this stage, let's investigate the sequence $b_1, b_2, b_3, ... \ $. Having the fact that $2^{b_{i+1}}$ has $b_i+1$ digits, implies:

$$b_i<\log_{10} (2^{b_{i+1}}) <b_i+1 \implies b_i \log_2 (10)<b_{i+1}<(b_i+1)(\log_2 (10)).$$

So, we can set $b_{i+1}=1+[b_i \log_2 (10)].$ Note that, in this way, the sequence $b_1, b_2, b_3, ... \ $ is also increasing.

As the original solution suggests, we have $b_{i+1} \leq (1+\log_2 (10))^i$.

To finish the problem, observe that for every $k$, there is $m$ such that $b_{m+1}>k\geq b_m.$ So,

$$\frac{\text{sum of the digits of }a^k}{\log k} \geq \frac{m-2}{\log b_{m+1}} \geq \frac{m-2}{m(\log(1+\log_2 (10)))}.$$

We are done but please note that there are still some special cases (for examples what happens if $m<2$ or $m \to \infty$?), which should be considered.

Comment: @RazaRajaei, I took the liberty to fix the formatting on the text in the MathJax. You can use \text{} to display text in MathJax.

Comment: @Sahaj I see, Thank you!